# Error submiting application to myapps.developer.ubuntu.com

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm uploading an 11mb app (it's an ubuntu phone html5 app) to https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com and then uploads to 100% and starts again to 100% and finally appears this error:

""The submitted files could not be uploaded, please try again.

Please include the following information when reporting this issue:

CONTEXT: onUploadFailed
STATUS_CODE: 400
RESPONSE: {"successful": false, "errors": {"timestamp": ["Timestamp is expired."]}}
""
I've tried again and again with same result, using other browsers and other networks.
I can upload other apps (I've tried to upload a webapp and I can upload it).

Comment: I just tested uploading a file myself and it's fine. Maybe try again now?

Comment: Seems your file is obviously way bigger than mine which might be why yours fails and mine succeeds. After how long does it fail?

Comment: Today. It works now using fast network, with slow network fails... if upload needs one or more minutes then fails.

Comment: Spoke to the developers and they're working on a fix which extends the timeout. Thanks for reporting the issue!

Comment: Actually error persists... is not solved.

Comment: I've been told that a workaround has been rolled out which should prevent this happening. It will still fail if your upload takes a very long time.